# How to implement Persistent TokenCache i.e. SQL or any other persistent methods in .Net framework 4.8

Tags: authentication, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a .Net Framework 4.8 application. Recently I migrated the authentication from Azure AD graph to Microsoft Graph as Microsoft if removing support for ADAL. As part of that I have created BuildConfidentialClientApplication() method which gets token and stores in DistributedMemoryCache. But this is not suggested for Production environment. So I want to store the token in SQL but the relevant classes are not available. Could you help me to identify the required classes to implement SQL based memory cache.

Here is the existing code and I want to implement SQL memory cache.

```
public static IConfidentialClientApplication BuildConfidentialClientApplication()
    {
        if (clientapp == null)
        {
            clientapp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(AuthenticationConfig.ClientId)
                  .WithClientSecret(AuthenticationConfig.ClientSecret)
                  .WithRedirectUri(AuthenticationConfig.RedirectUri)
                  .WithAuthority(new Uri(AuthenticationConfig.Authority))
                  .Build();

            clientapp.AddDistributedTokenCache(services =>
            {
                // Do not use DistributedMemoryCache in production!
                // This is a memory cache which is not distributed and is not persisted.
                // It's useful for testing and samples, but in production use a durable distributed cache,
                // such as Redis.
                services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();


                // The setting below shows encryption which works on a single machine. 
                // In a distributed system, the encryption keys must be shared between all machines
                
                services.Configure<MsalDistributedTokenCacheAdapterOptions>(o =>
                {
                    o.Encrypt = true;
                });
            });

        }
        return clientapp;
    }
```

This code is having issue in Production after few weeks and getting into trouble. Please help.